# React - Warning: An update was scheduled from inside an update function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, warnings, setstate

I am dealing with a lot of problems about updating states in React for validation purposes, and always my state update after the render or something like that, anyway, I saw that many people solve this using a callback function in the `setState`, but it always throws the following warning.

> Warning: An update (setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate) was
>   scheduled from inside an update function. Update functions should be
>   pure, with zero side-effects. Consider using componentDidUpdate or a
>   callback.

I tried to update inside `componentDidUpdate`, but that results in an infinite loop.

This is my `setState` with the callback function.

```
state = {
    index: 0,
    activeInput: '',
    errors: {
      error: false,
      errorNombre: false,
      errorCuil: false,
      errorEmail: false,
      errorContrasena: false,
      errorCalle: false,
      errorNumero: false,
      errorProvincia: false,
      errorLocalidad: false
  },
    values: {...this.props.initialValues}
  };

    _onChangeValue = (name, value) => {
        this.setState(prevState => {
          return {
            values: {
              ...prevState.values,
              [name]: value
            }
          }, this.validate(name)
        })
      };
```

And this is the Validate Function, is a switch, so i much longer but the problem maybe could be that every case has another setState inside...

```
validate = input => {

    switch(input){
      case 'nombre':
        let { nombre } = this.state.values
        let splitNombre = nombre.split(' ');

        if ( splitNombre.length > 1 && splitNombre[1].length === 0 || nombre.length === 0 || splitNombre.length === 1 ) {
          this.setState(prevState => ({
            errors: { ...prevState.errors, error: true, errorNombre: true }
          }));
        } else {
          this.setState(prevState => ({
            errors: { ...prevState.errors, error: false, errorNombre: false }
          }));
        }
        break
```

As this is a compound component is a little messy but here is the files

Input.js

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';

class Input extends PureComponent {
  _onChangeText = text => {
    this.props.onChangeValue(this.props.name, text);
  };

  render() {
    const { onChangeValue, name, ...rest } = this.props;
    return (
      <input {...rest} onChange={(event) => this._onChangeText(event.target.value)} />
    );
  }
}

export default Input;
```

Steps.js

```
import Botones from './Botones'

    export default class Step extends PureComponent {
        state = {}
        render() {
          return (
            <Fragment>

              {this.props.children({
                onChangeValue: this.props.onChangeValue,
                values: this.props.values,
                index: this.props.index,
                errors: this.props.errors
              })}

              <div>
            <Botones currentIndex={this.props.currentIndex}
                     prevStep={this.props.prevStep}
                     nextStep={this.props.nextStep}
                     onSubmit={this.props.onSubmit}
                     isLast={this.props.isLast}
                     isFirst={this.props.isFirst}
                     error={this.props.errors.error}    
            />

          </div>
        </Fragment>
      )
    }
  }
```

FirstStep.js

```
import Steps from './Steps';

export default class FirstStep extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {}
    }

    render() {
        //console.log(this.props)
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <Steps level={this.props.index}/>
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} className="mt90">
                    <div>
                        <label>Nombre completo</label>
                        <input type="text"
                               name="nombre"
                               placeholder="Escriba su nombre"
                               onChange={ event => this.props.onChangeText('nombre', event.target.value) }
                               value={this.props.values.nombre}
                               className={ `${ this.props.errors.errorNombre && "error-focus" }` }
                               />
                        { this.props.errors.errorNombre &&
                        <span className="error">No es un nombre completo</span> }
                    </div>
                    <div className="mt50">
                        <label>N° de CUIL</label>
                        <input type="text"
                               name="cuil"
                               placeholder="Ej.: 23-45678901-2"
                               onChange={ event => this.props.onChangeText('cuil', event.target.value) }
                               value={this.props.values.cuil}
                               className={ `${ this.props.errors.errorCuil && "error-focus" }` }
                               />
                        { this.props.errors.errorCuil &&
                        <span className="error">No es un CUIL válido</span> }
                    </div>
                </form>
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

App.js (has the FirstStep as a child component)

```
[...]
Render()
<RegisterBox.Step>
            { ({ values, onChangeValue, index, errors }) => (
              <FirstStep values={values} onChangeText={onChangeValue} index={index} errors={errors} />
            )}
          </RegisterBox.Step>
[...]
```

Comment: Try moving `this.validate(name)` outside of your setState method

Comment: That works but is not validating at the same time when you type in the input.. i mean, when i need a 11 lenght name, only when i type 12 times checks that it is Ok, i was trying this to make the change inmediatly because i can't call it in render (infinite loop)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you've made a small typographical error. Your solution should look a bit more like this.

```
_onChangeValue = (name, value) => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        values: {
          ...prevState.values,
          [name]: value
        }
      }
    }, () => this.validate(name));
  };
```

Notice the call to `this.validate` has moved out one set of brackets. Secondly, it's been wrapped in an anonymous function, so that it can actually be used as a callback.

I imagine this would have resulted in some confusing behaviour. Because of the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), your setState would not have made any update to values, instead updating state with only the results of your validation!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to rethink about this problem. To make sure that we are in the same pace, let me reiterate several things.

First of all `setState` is asynchronous and more like a signal to React to update the state object and invokes functions of React life cycle.

Nested `setState` is discouraged since it's hard to reason about the behavior of asynchronous calls.

You need to restructure your functions to avoid nested `setState`. I can't do that for you in this brief answer and you know the best how you want to do so. One thing that you need to notice is that sometimes, you could serialize `setState` calls to make sure that the prevState you are seeing in this current `setState` call is actually from the previous call. A way to make it work is to wrap `setState` with a `Promise` and use `await/async` to serialize the calls.

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Huy Doan, I'm kinda amateur so my practices are not pretty well, promises could fix the problem i guess so i will try it! Thx